# Quesion about the VBA function of continuous cap look up

Tags: option-pricing, fixed-income, vba

Here is the VBA function to calculate the cap price

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is N and t0? From the textbook, N = the number of reset (or payment) dates and  t0 = time until the first reset date. But can we find out the N and t0 of the option from the website?

Comment: The cap is a sum of caplets, the N is the number of caplets constituting your cap.

Comment: Can we find the N from some website??

Comment: can we get the input for testing from any website??